# CRUD Testing with Jupiter in spring boots giving error:jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, junit

**Error for test 1 - org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [final com.orrs.authmicro.customer.CustomerService customerService] in constructor [public com.orrs.authmicro.AuthMicroApplicationTests(com.orrs.authmicro.customer.CustomerService,com.orrs.authmicro.customer.CustomerRepository)].**

**Error for Test 2 -org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [final com.orrs.authmicro.customer.CustomerService customerService] in constructor [public com.orrs.authmicro.AuthMicroApplicationTests(com.orrs.authmicro.customer.CustomerService,com.orrs.authmicro.customer.CustomerRepository)].**

I have looked at most of the solutions available and they advice to remove @Test or @ParameterizedTest . My tests are not found if I remove @Test and I cant remove @ParameterizedTest because I'm not using it. I have spent hours already and can't seem to overcome this. Before this there were **Bean Creation Errors--- UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name customerService**

**Testfile**

```
package com.orrs.authmicro;

import com.orrs.authmicro.customer.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@AllArgsConstructor
@DataJpaTest
class AuthMicroApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    @Test
    public void testJpaSave(){
        Customer customer = customerRepository.save(new Customer(
                "TestFname",
                "TestLname",
                "TestAddress",
                "99999999999",
                Gender.MALE,
                "TestPassword",
                "testEmail@gmail.com",
                CustomerRole.USER
        ));


        assertThat(customer.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }



    @Test
    public void testRegistration(){



        String response = customerService.signUpCustomer(
                new Customer(
                        "TestFname",
                        "TestLname",
                        "TestAddress",
                        "99999999999",
                        Gender.MALE,
                        "TestPassword",
                        "testEmail@gmail.com",
                        CustomerRole.USER
                )
        );

        assertThat(response.equals("Signed up perfectly)"));
    }

}
```

**CustomerRespository**

```
package com.orrs.authmicro.customer;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    Optional<Customer> findByEmail(String email);


}
```

**CustomerService**

```
package com.orrs.authmicro.customer;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerService implements UserDetailsService {



    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    private final String  USER_NOT_FOUND = "Customer with email %s not found";
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return customerRepository.findByEmail(email)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND,email)));
    }
    public String signUpCustomer(Customer customer){
        boolean customerExists = customerRepository.findByEmail(customer.getEmail())
                .isPresent();
        if(customerExists){
            throw new IllegalStateException("User with Email already exist!");
        }

        if(customer.getPassword() == ""){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Password cannot be empty");
        }

        if(customer.getFname() == "" || customer.getFname().isEmpty()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Name cannot be empty");
        }

        if(customer.getGender().equals("")){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Gender cannot be empty");
        }

        if(customer.getAddress().equals("")){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Address cannot be empty");
        }

        String encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(customer.getPassword());
        customer.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        customerRepository.save(customer);

        return "Signed up perfectly";
    }

    public String currentUsername(Principal principal){
        return principal.getName();
    }




    public Customer updateCustomer(Customer customer){

        //Object principal =  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        //String userName = currentUsername((Principal) principal);

        boolean customerExists = customerRepository.findByEmail(customer.getEmail()).isPresent();
        if(customerExists){

            Optional<Customer> wrapperCustomer = customerRepository.findByEmail(customer.getEmail());
            Customer  existingCustomer = wrapperCustomer.get();
            existingCustomer.setAddress(customer.getAddress());
            existingCustomer.setFname(customer.getFname());
            existingCustomer.setLname(customer.getLname());
            existingCustomer.setPhoneNumber(customer.getPhoneNumber());
            existingCustomer.setGender(customer.getGender());
            customerRepository.save(existingCustomer);
            return existingCustomer;
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("User doesn't exist");
        }


    }
    public String deleteCustomerById(String email){
        boolean customerExists = customerRepository.findByEmail(email).isPresent();
        if(customerExists){

            Optional<Customer> wrapperCustomer = customerRepository.findByEmail(email);
            Customer  existingCustomer = wrapperCustomer.get();
            customerRepository.deleteById(existingCustomer.getId());

            return "Customer Deleted Successfully!";

        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("User Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.orrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-micro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth-micro</name>
    <description>Authorisation microservice</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `@AllArgsConstructor` in combination with unit tests means you're asking JUnit to inject all fields in the constructor, not Spring. Why don't you a) remove the annotation, b) remove the `final` from both fields, and c) add `@Autowired` to the `customerRepository` field? Your test class then only has a default no-args constructor, which allows JUnit to create instances of it. The autowiring will be done by Spring.

Comment: @RobSpoor Thank You so much. Both tests worked. Why did i have to remove final? and why was JUnit trying to inject all fields instead of Spring? Does Junit only work with no args constructor by default? you're telling me the control transfers from Spring to Junit and then to Spring. Sorry about this but can you tell me where can I get this knowledge from?

Comment: If you don't remove final, then the compiler will complain that the fields will not have been set. That's what you needed the `@AllArgsConstructor` for. But JUnit doesn't work that way. When it encounters a method or constructor argument that it can't handle by default (like `TestInfo`), it checks the available extensions (like `SpringExtension`) if one of them can provide it. If none can, then JUnit will fail, as you have seen.

Comment: You can also try to re-add what you removed, but then also add an `@Autowired` to the `customerRepository` field. Perhaps that will make the `SpringExtension`, which is enabled because of the `DataJpaTest`, provide a value for JUnit. Without the annotation the field has no special meaning for JUnit and no special meaning for Spring, which means neither will try to provide a value for it.